# How to find out the correct path for ANT_HOME in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, environment-variables, ant

I'm using Ubuntu `14.04` (on a VirtualBox VM) and installed Apache Ant via `aptitude`:

```
$ aptitude install ant
```

The binary is stored in `/usr/bin/`:

```
$ which ant
/usr/bin/ant
```

Now I want to set `ANT_HOME` and also add it to my `PATH` environment variable. On Windows it would be easy to find the correct folder -- `ANT_HOME` is the folder, where the installation is stored and looks like `C:\Program Files\Apache Ant` (or simply the parent directory of the folder with the Ant binaries).

**How to find out the correct path for `ANT_HOME` in a Linux system (e.g. Ubuntu Server)?**

---

**UPDATE**

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-7054/gickh/index.html) on the Oracle website says:

> Add the following lines to the file, substituting the directory where you installed Ant:
>
> `ANT_HOME=/apache-install-dir/apache-ant-version`

How to find out the path to the `apache-install-dir`?

Comment: use export ANT_HOME='/usr/bin', or use this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-7054/gickh/index.html) provided by oracle

Comment: @AlinAndrei Thanks for your comment, but what I'd actually like to know is not how to set the environment variable, but _how_ to know / _how_ to find out, which path for `ANT_HOME` is correct on a Linux machine. So did you mean, the `ANT_HOME` is always the folder with executables, where the Ant executable is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On CentOS/Ubuntu ANT_HOME should be **/usr/share/ant/**. You can check /usr/share/ant/bin/ant, it's just a bash script

```
# load system-wide ant configuration (ONLY if ANT_HOME has NOT been set)
  if [ -z "$ANT_HOME" -o "$ANT_HOME" = "/usr/share/ant" ]; then
      if [ -f "/etc/ant.conf" ] ; then
          . /etc/ant.conf
      fi
  fi
```

So if you didn't specify explicitly ANT_HOME, /usr/share/ant will be used by default.

Comment: Thank you very much fr your answer! Could you please (if possible) add a reference to it, where you have the info from. Thanks

Comment: As I have told above, I've just checked the script /usr/share/ant/bin/ant